# Error while using Google Calendar API in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-calendar-api

I am pretty new to Rails and had been following this [tutorial](https://readysteadycode.com/howto-integrate-google-calendar-with-rails) to integrate Google Calendar into my Application. The basic idea was to access a client's Google Calendar and be able to add events through the app itself.

Everything worked well till the redirect method in the tutorial. The problem started with callback method. Once I hit the redirect method and allow access I come up with this error.
   **IPAddr::InvalidAddressError in AppointmentsController#callback**

Here is my AppointmentsController

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController

def redirect
  client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
  redirect_to client.authorization_uri.to_s
end


def callback
  client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
  client.code = params[:code]
  response = client.fetch_access_token!
  session[:authorization] = response
  redirect_to calendars_url
end


def calendars
 client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
 client.update!(session[:authorization])
 service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
 service.authorization = client
 @calendar_list = service.list_calendar_lists
 rescue Google::Apis::AuthorizationError
   response = client.refresh!
 session[:authorization] = session[:authorization].merge(response)
   retry
   end


def new_event
 client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
 client.update!(session[:authorization])
 service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
 service.authorization = client
 today = Date.today
 event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new({
  start: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(date: today),
  end: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventDateTime.new(date: today + 1),
  summary: 'New event!'
})

service.insert_event(params[:calendar_id], event)

redirect_to events_url(calendar_id: params[:calendar_id])
 end

 private

def client_options
{
  client_id: Rails.application.secrets.google_client_id,
  client_secret: Rails.application.secrets.google_client_secret,
  authorization_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
  token_credential_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  scope: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::AUTH_CALENDAR,
  redirect_uri: callback_url
}
 end
end
```

Here is my **routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :contacts
resources :payments
resources :expenses
devise_for :users
resources :products

root to: "products#index"
get '/redirect', to: 'appointments#redirect', as: 'redirect'
get '/callback', to: 'appointments#callback', as: 'callback'
get '/calendars', to: 'appointments#calendars', as: 'calendars'
get '/events/:calendar_id', to: 'appointments#events', as: 'events', 
calendar_id: /[^\/]+/
post '/events/:calendar_id', to: 'appointments#new_event', as: 
'new_event', calendar_id: /[^\/]+/
  end
```

Does anyone has an idea how to fix this error? The error is given on the line

```
response = client.fetch_access_token!
```

Note : I was already using devise as an authentication method.
I did an extensive search and could not find anything. I would be really grateful if someone helps me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're probably running this in development.  If so,  your callback_url is probably localhost, which Google can't direct to.

Use https://ngrok.com/ to set up external tunnelling and then in place of `callback_url` use the ngrok supplied address with "/callback" appended.

Comment: What do you mean by callback_url? The one I am using in secrets.yml?

Comment: I have faced serious issues with integrating Google APIs in rails. I refer to this excellent article which solves the problem of integrating the api properly - http://blog.jieck.com/server-side-integrates-google-analytics-api-with-ruby/. It is for analytics but you can easily change the provider to Calendar. As far as callback is concerned, you can use `http://localhost:3000/oauth2callback` without any issues. Just register it in the console as well.

Comment: Also, you have not defined or showed in the code posted what actually is the variable `callback_url`

Comment: `callback_url` is a method automatically created by your named route `callback` in `routes rb`. It's the full URL to your callback so (for example) if your app was running on www.foo.com the callback_url would be "www.foo.com/callback" and if your running in development your callback_url is "localhost:3000/callback" which just means you are calling a html server on your own machine. When Google is told to go to "localhost:3000/callback" there's no way it can connect that to your own IP address.

Comment: Ngrok.com is a service that gives you an external  URL address that can run anywhere in the world and connects to your localhost. Visit the site and they explain more there. If you're running ngrok you can give Google a URL that actually connects back to your development machine.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn I used ngrok.com for the localhost tunneling, it still gives me the same error. I am now completely helpless. Do you have any workaround?

Comment: So, ngrok gave you an address, right?  I dunno, something like "https://xxxx.mygrok.io" ?  Now change your code so instead of `redirect_uri: callback_url` you have `redirect_uri: 'http://xxx.mygrok.io/callback'` using whatever your ngrok domain is. That should get you farther along.